# Play 2 Compiler Error: bad symbolic reference to scala.xml (IntelliJ 14.1.4 + Play 2.4.2)

Tags: playframework

I created a new Play 2.4.2 application in IntelliJ 14.1.4 with the help of instructions for Intellij on Play site (I have Scala plugin installed and enabled). Instead of Scala I selected Java project. When I try to run created app, I get the following error:

```
Error:Play 2 Compiler:  bad symbolic reference to scala.xml encountered in class file 'BaseScalaTemplate.class'.
Error:Play 2 Compiler:  Cannot access term xml in package scala. The current classpath may be
Error:Play 2 Compiler:  missing a definition for scala.xml, or BaseScalaTemplate.class may have been compiled against a version that's
Error:Play 2 Compiler:  incompatible with the one found on the current classpath.
Error:Play 2 Compiler: 
 (NOTE: It looks like the scala-xml module is missing; try adding a dependency on "org.scala-lang.modules" : "scala-xml".
        See http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/scala-2.11.html for more information.)
 bad symbolic reference to scala.xml encountered in class file 'BaseScalaTemplate.class'.
Error:Play 2 Compiler: 
 (NOTE: It looks like the scala-xml module is missing; try adding a dependency on "org.scala-lang.modules" : "scala-xml".
        See http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/scala-2.11.html for more information.)
 two errors found
Error:Play 2 Compiler: 
 (compile:compile) Compilation failed
 Total time: 29 s, completed 16.08.2015. 16:33:39
```

I checked dependencies (File->Project Structure->Modules->Dependencies) and "org.scala-lang.modules":"scala-xml" seems to be added.

Does anybody know where is the problem ? I am new to Play framework. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you create the Play project? With `activator new`?

Comment: I created the project with IntelliJ wizard, I didn't use `activator new`. I clicked on Create New Project -> Java -> Play 2. However, when I create project with `activator` and make import in IntelliJ, everything is ok.

Comment: I would use activator for project creation. Because the Play plugin is not always up to date. Play release new versions and users then can report bugs to IntelliJ to fix them. Perhaps if you use older version of Play this could work, but I am not sure, I always use `activator` and then code in IntelliJ.

Comment: I agree with you. It seems that IntelliJ or Play plugin have some issues with project creation. Thank you for your response.